# Code.Grandtotal() variable Resetting on new page in SSRS

Tags: ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I have a complex expression that calculates the revenue depending on a bill type. It basically says if Bill type = Progress use X calculation , If Bill type = NTE use Y calculation , for everything else use Z. Because this is an Aggregate you can not sum up a total simply by using a sum function in SSRS. You need to use custom code. I have been using the following that I found on Stack. See below.

```
Public Shared Dim grandTotal as Decimal
Public Shared Dim costCenterTotal as Decimal
Public Shared Dim workerTotal as Decimal

Public Shared Function Initialize() 
    grandTotal = 0
    costCenterTotal = 0
    workerTotal = 0
End Function

Public Function AddTotal(ByVal b AS Decimal) AS Decimal
    grandTotal = grandTotal + b
    costCenterTotal = costCenterTotal + b
    workerTotal = workerTotal  + b
    return b
End Function

Public Function GetWorkerTotal()
   Dim ret as Decimal = workerTotal
   workerTotal = 0
   return ret
End Function 

Public Function GetCostCenterTotal()
    Dim ret as Decimal = costCenterTotal 
    costCenterTotal = 0
    return ret
End Function 

Public Function GetGrandTotal()
    Dim ret as Decimal = grandTotal
    grandTotal= 0
    return ret
End Function
```

In my main expression I added the code.AddTotal() function to the expression and in the total line I used the code.GetGrandTotal() Function in the column.

The issue is that when I run the report I do not get the right total in the Grand     Total Line . It seems to change depending on if I view each page of the report and even if I view all pages the Grand total is not correct. It seems to reset .  Can some one tell me what I am doing wrong. 
Thanks.

Comment: Are you repeating the Grand Total on multiple pages? I think it would reset after each use due to the **GrandTotal = 0**. Maybe try removing that line.

Comment: I would reproduce the calculations in your SQL.